# Find all patterns in a string php

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

This is my string.

```
$str = '"additional_details":" {"mode_of_transport":"air"}"}],"additional_details":"{"mode_of_transport":"air"}"}],"additional_details":"{"mode_of_transport":"air"}"}],';
```

I want to find all patterns that start with `"{"` and end with `"}"`.

I am trying this:

```
preg_match_all( '/"(\{.*\})"/', $json, $matches );
print_r($matches);
```

It gives me an output of:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => "{"mode_of_transport":"air"}"}],"additional_details":"{"mode_of_transport":"air"}"}],"additional_details":"{"mode_of_transport":"air"}"
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => {"mode_of_transport":"air"}"}],"additional_details":"{"mode_of_transport":"air"}"}],"additional_details":"{"mode_of_transport":"air"}
        )

)
```

See the array key 1. It gives all matches in one key and other details too.

I want an array of all matches. Like

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => "{"mode_of_transport":"air"}"}],"additional_details":"{"mode_of_transport":"air"}"}],"additional_details":"{"mode_of_transport":"air"}"
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => {"mode_of_transport":"air"},
            [1] => {"mode_of_transport":"air"},
            [2] => {"mode_of_transport":"air"}
        )

)
```

What should I change in my pattern.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
preg_match_all( '/({[^}]*})/', $str, $matches );
print_r($matches[1]);
Array
(
    [0] => {"mode_of_transport":"air"}
    [1] => {"mode_of_transport":"air"}
    [2] => {"mode_of_transport":"air"}
)
```